# How do I set visibility of each shape in the array for a given amount of time?

Tags: android, libgdx, shapes

So I am using the libgdx framework and am new to android games development. I have an array of yellow circle objects stored in each index which are shown on the game screen when I run them, all the circle objects are in different x positions but on the same y axis. I want to basically set the visibility of each circle for a given amount of time before the next one becomes visible for say 1000 ms per circle. So for example circle 1 will be visible for 1000 ms then it will become invisible and circle 2 will then become visible for 1000ms so on and so forth, till I reach the end of the list.

```
public class Spot {

private float x;
private float y;
private float radius;

private Circle spot;
private Circle spotList[];

public Spot(float x, float y, float radius, int amount){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    spot = new Circle(x,y,radius);
    spotList = new Circle[amount];

    for(int i = 0; i < spotList.length; i++){

        spotList[i] = new Circle(this.x+(i*15), this.y, this.radius);

    }
}

public void update(float delta){


}


public Float getX(){

    return x;
}

public Float getY(){

    return y;
}

public float getRadius(){

    return radius;
}

public Circle[] getSpots(){

    return spotList;
}

public Circle getSpot(){

    return spot;
}
```

}

The rendering of the shape has been outsourced to a different class I want to be able to handle the visibility of the circles etc in the update method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not using Actors (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d), you need to keep track of time yourself and make the circles visible/not visible.

You will want to add

```
private float elapsedTime = 0.0f;
private float currentCircle = 0;
```

two fields, one for keeping track of elapsed time and one for the currently visible circle.

```
public void update(float delta){
    elapsedTime += delta;
    if (elapsedTime >= 1.0f) { // more than one second passed
        spot[currentCircle].setVisible(false);
        if (currentCircle + 1 < spotList.size()) {
          currentCircle++;
            spot[currentCircle].setVisible(true);
            elapsedTime -= 1.0f; // reset timer (don't just set to 0.0f to avoid time shifts)
        }
    }
}
```

In the update method, count elapsedTime and if more then one seconds passed, make old circle not visible and new circle visible. Also make sure that initially the first circle is visible and that the timer is 0.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use the [Universal Tween Engine](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/) which works well with the libGDX framework. Visit the link to see how to include it in your project and for documentation.

As a quick demonstration on how to use it:-

1. Create and instantiate a TweenManager and your array of Spots in your class responsible for rendering.

   ```
   protected TweenManager tweenManager = new TweenManager();
   Spot spots[] = new Spot[...];
   ...
   ```
2. Create your timer by implementing the TweenCallback()

   ```
   final int numberOfSpots = 5;
   int spotArrayIndex = 0;
   float timeDelay = 1000f; /*1000 milliseconds*/

   Tween.call(new TweenCallback() {
   @Override
   public void onEvent(int type, BaseTween<?> source) {
      /*set or unset the visibility of your Spot objects here i.e. */
      spots[spotArrayIndex++].setVisible(false); /*Set current spot invisible*/
      spots[spotArrayIndex].setVisible(true); /*Set next spot to be visible*/

   }
   }).repeat(numberOfSpots, timeDelay).start(tweenManager);
   ```
3. Update the tweenManager in your render method

   ```
   public void render(float delta) {
   ...
       tweenManger.update(delta);
   ...
   }
   ```

Please check the code for errors if you use it, as I am not sure of the rest of your code.